# using Rcpp with boost/regex ,Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'libboost_regex' not found

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

when using Rcpp with boost/regex, Build&reload show

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'libboost_regex' not found
```

Error : unable to load R code in package ‘genia’ 
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘genia’

I have set

```
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS="-L/Users/name/software/cpp_boost/lib -lboost_regex")
Sys.setenv(PKG_CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/name/software/cpp_boost/include -I../inst/include")
```

but, using sourceCpp(), It's ok. I want to know how to solve the problems.

Comment: Do you have an object called `libboost_regex` sitting around in one of your R scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Boost with libraries works in [this full example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/) from the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

I recommend you start by replicating that example -- just call `sourceCpp()` on the code saved into a file -- and then start from there.